# I made this program to convert from binary to decimal but why is it not working please tell (in python)

Tags: python

```
numb=input('enter binary number : ')
s=0
p=1
for items in numb:
  s+=int(numb)*(2**(len(numb)-p))
  p+=1
print(s)  


here i used a simple math's from which we go through to convert binary to decimal.
```

i tried to break the number inputted by user (from front) and then converting it to int and then multiplying it by 2 whoe's power is at first one less than number of elements in our input number.
this process goes on by adding previous p. so logically i think its correct.

Comment: `int(numb)` should be `int(items)`. I think you’re doing yourself a disservice by using less-than-obvious variable names. If you rename `numb` to `binary_number`, `items` to `bit`, and so on, I think you would’ve been able to spot your mistake yourself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you v. much julia ,that was a very kiddish mistake in which i was stuck badly.

Answer (score 1):

```
s+=int(numb)*(2**(len(numb)-p))
```

should be

```
s += int(items) * (2 ** (len(numb) - p))
```

Note the change from `numb` to `items`.

Secondly note that this can basically just be simplified to

```
print(int(input('enter binary number : '), 2))
```

Comment: Thank you v. much luk2302 for your precious help and time.